# I have generated wsdl to apex but when i hit php class to get output it gives read out exception

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I am able to generate apex from a wsdl. This wsdl returns output from a php class. it works fine when I call it from another php client class, but when I call it from apex it gives an error "IO exception Read out time out".

Please do not advise me to use php toolkit as  i am not getting output from salesforce.

I am trying to hit a php class from salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PHP web service endpoint URL has been added as a *Remote Site* under *Setup > Remote Site Settings*.

Comment: Sounds like the PHP endpoint may be blocking requests from Salesforce?  Do you have any IP or other restrictions on the server that might be preventing Salesforce from calling the PHP server?

Comment: Thanks ArtieBrosius!I found the solution myself.i was not providing username and password in apex class.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to generate oauth token on phpwebserver as i do not want to store username and password in apex class.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the default web service callout timeout. You will want to increase the value of the `timeout_x` property in the wsdl2apex generated class. The value is in milliseconds and can set up to 120 seconds.

See [Apex Web Services and Callouts - Additional Considerations](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Additional_Considerations)

Comment: Yes i already did remote site setting and also used timeout option in my code but error is same.And yes my php class is giving output in std class(object)and  when i call this class  from jsp client then i an getting output in form of an id like result= testuri.getuserarray@4555fdh

Comment: Thanks Daniel for support ! I found the solution.But i have another question.Now i do not want to store server username and password in http header on Salesforce while making request for data.So can you help me with Oauth functionality. So that i can generate token on PHp webserver and store it on salesforce side to make futher request.

Comment: @Shivani, great. Glad you got your issue sorted. If any of the answers here helped you could mark them as the solution or add another answer with the required details. For the oauth I'd suggest searching the existing questions or asking a new separate question.